# Looping with Linked List Functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers, while-loop, linked-list

I am new at c++ and linked lists.

This code is meant to read letters and numbers as instructions from a command file and execute functions on linked lists accordingly. The command file starts with a 'r' and '1'- a read instruction.

My code reads and then carries out the first letter instruction. It then crashes and stops executing the remaining instructions. However, each of the letters work fine if called after the read, so I am not sure if there is an issue with the while loop or the functions - pointer problems most likely.

Odd thing is this code worked fine previously and now it keeps getting stuck.
Can someone spot what is the problem and help me out please.

Thanks

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

typedef int item;
struct node {
   item data;
   node* next;
   };
typedef node* nodeptr;

void add_to_list (item number, nodeptr &hdlist);
item get_from_list(nodeptr &hdlist);
void read (string file_number, nodeptr &hdlist);
void print_all (nodeptr hdlist);
void write (nodeptr hdlist, ofstream &output_file);
void entries(nodeptr hdlist, string file_number);

int main()
{
    nodeptr hdlist = NULL;
    ifstream command_file;
    string command_filename;

    cin >> command_filename;

    command_file.open(command_filename.c_str());

    if (!command_file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "file not found" << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    vector<string> commands;
    string line;

    while (getline(command_file, line))
    {
        commands.push_back(line);
    }

    command_file.close();

    string file_number, value_to_delete, value_to_insert;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < commands.size())
    {   
        char input = (commands[i])[0];

        if (input == 'i')
        {
            print_all(hdlist);  
        }
        else if (input == 'r')
        {   file_number = (commands[i+1]);
            i++;
            read (file_number, hdlist);
        }
        else if (input == 'w')
        {
            ofstream output_file;
            string output_filename = "output_" + file_number + ".txt";
            output_file.open(output_filename.c_str(),ios::app);

            if (!output_file.is_open())
            {
                cout << "file not found" << endl;
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            write(hdlist, output_file);

            output_file.close();
        }
        else if (input == 'e')
        {
            entries(hdlist, file_number);
        }
        else
        {
            i = commands.size() + 1;
        }

        i++;
        //cout << hdlist << endl;
    }
}

void add_to_list (item number, nodeptr &hdlist)
{
    nodeptr newnode = new node;
    newnode->data = number;
    newnode->next = hdlist;
    hdlist = newnode;
}

item get_from_list (nodeptr &hdlist)
{
    int number;
    nodeptr nowptr;
    nowptr = hdlist;
    number = nowptr->data;
    hdlist = nowptr->next;
    delete nowptr;
    return item(number);
}

void print_all (nodeptr hdlist)
{
    if (hdlist != NULL)
    {
        print_all(hdlist->next);
        cout << get_from_list(hdlist) << endl;
    }
}

void read (string file_number, nodeptr &hdlist)
{
    string line;
    ifstream data_file;
    string data_filename = "data_" + file_number + ".txt";;
    data_file.open(data_filename.c_str());

    if (!data_file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "file not found" << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (getline(data_file, line))
    {
        stringstream ss;
        int num;
        ss << line;
        ss >> num;
        add_to_list(num,hdlist);
    }

    data_file.close();
}

void write (nodeptr hdlist, ofstream &output_file)
{
        if (hdlist != NULL)
        {
            write(hdlist->next, output_file);
            output_file << get_from_list(hdlist) << endl;

        }
}

void entries(nodeptr hdlist, string file_number)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (hdlist != NULL)
    {
        get_from_list(hdlist);
        count++;
    }

    ofstream output_file;
    string output_filename = "output_" + file_number + ".txt";
    output_file.open(output_filename.c_str(),ios::app);

    if (!output_file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "file not found" << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    output_file << "Number of elements in the list:" << count << endl;

    output_file.close();

}
```

Example of command file

```
r
1
w
e
i
w
```

Comment: please provide the complete source code,

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `hdlist` will not be changed after execution of function `write()` because the first parameter is passed by value and then function `entries()` will try to delete an invalid pointer. So

```
void write (nodeptr hdlist, ofstream &output_file);
void entries(nodeptr hdlist, string file_number);
```

should be

```
void write (nodeptr &hdlist, ofstream &output_file);
void entries(nodeptr &hdlist, string file_number);
```